# How can I disable the default PHP error catching in Drupal?

Tags: theming, debugging

I'm not accustomed to being so limited by a CMS whereby I have to use it's built-in error reporting instead of more specific logging with native PHP error logging.

Is it possible to disable the error catching which happens at `[site-root]/admin/reports/dblog` so that I can output my own variable dumps to my PHP logs via `error_log(print_r($var,true))`?

Comment: Note that I'm fine with doing something different if there's  a different logging syntax that will dump properly to my log file, doesn't have to be `error_log(print_r($var,true))`

Comment: You could simply disable the dblog module and add your own error logging functions to the html.tpl.php file in your themes directory. But if you are looking for development, I'd recommend installing devel module and use dpm() to dump variables.

Comment: You can also create your own hook into watchdog() via https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_watchdog/7 and then in there decide on what you want logged elsewhere